# Load file that is duplicated in two jars

Tags: android, jar

Hi I have two jars in my Android Studio project that contains common files and when i try launch app appears this error `duplicate files in jar generate apk`.

I see that to fix this it's need write this en buid.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'filename'
}
```

But this solution only ignore files but when I try to load its not are in package.

Other solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Remove any one `.jar` file then

Comment: The idea, is that these two jar could be in same project..